# Scheme - foo (x y) is not calling the recursive call

Tags: recursion, scheme

foo(x Y) is a procedure that has to solve this problem in the 
[Picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtZ4H.png)
Here is my Scheme Code:

```
(define foo
  (lambda (x y)
    (if (<= y 0) (x) 0)
    (if (<= x 0) (y) 0)
    (if (>= x y) (+ x foo ((- x 1) (- y 2)))  0)
    (if (< x y) (+ y foo ((- x 2) (- y 3))) 0)))
```

when it test it for (foo 5 6) => it prints the same exact numbers, instead of 12 !! I don't know why it is not going through the recursive call..

Answer (score 3):

There is no recursive calls here. For it to be a call you need to have parentheses around it like `(foo (- x 2) (- y 3))`

Only the last `if` is regarded as becoming the result of the procedure. All the previous ones return a value and since it's not the last it discards the result and continues to the next. In order for several conditions to mean something they must be nested. Thus instead of the 0 you put the entire next `if`.

```
(define (foo x y)
  (if (<= x 0)
      x
      (if (<= y 0)
          y
          ...)))
```

There is also `cond` that makes a flatter structure that works as `if-elseif-else` in other languages.

```
(define (foo x y)
  (cond
    ((<= x 0) x)
    ((<= y 0) y)
    ...
    (else ...)))
```